# Laravel with fullcalendar with locale

Tags: laravel-5, fullcalendar, locale

I have a problem with locale in full Calendar in Laravel.
I use "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "~1.0" and i can't pass locale in FR.
If you have any idea, i take it.
Thanks

My Controller

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $events = [];

        $events[] = \Calendar::event(
            'Event One', //event title
            false, //full day event?
            '2017-07-31T1000', //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
            '2017-07-31T1200', //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
            0 //optionally, you can specify an event ID
        );

        $calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events)
                  ->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
            'header' => array('left' => 'prev,next today', 'center' => 'title', 'right' => ''),

            'locale' => 'fr',
            'editable'=> true,
            'navLinks'=> true,
            'selectable'  => true,
            'defaultView' => 'month'
    ])->setCallbacks([ //set fullcalendar callback options (will not be JSON encoded)
        'viewRender' => 'function() {alert("Callbacks!");}'
    ]);  //add an array with addEvents



        return view('agenda', array('calendar' => $calendar));
    }
```

Comment: Did you include the `fr` locale? (`<script src='fullcalendar/locale/fr.js'></script>`)

Answer (score 1):

1.Download the [fullcalendar package](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/download/v3.9.0/fullcalendar-3.9.0.zip).
2. Extract it wherever you like.
3. Go to the locale directory and copy the language files you need.
4. Go to your public/js directory and create a directory called 'fullcalendar' into which you paste the copied language files.
4. Alternatively, you could copy the files to the resources directory and compile them using laravel-mix.
5. Just below the fullcalendar script (e.g. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>`), add the language script using an if or switch condition, for example:

```
@if ($locale == 'fr') {{-- $locale is a predefined variable holding the user's locale--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar/fr.js') }}"></script>
@endif
```

6. You're all set!!

Answer (score 1):

One applicable solution is this:

Edit the options of default in the class `calendar`:

```
protected $defaultOptions = [
 'header' => [
     'left' => 'prev,next today',
     'center' => 'title',
     'right' => 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
 ],
 'monthNames' => ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
 'dayNames' => ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
 'dayNamesShort' => ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
 'monthNamesShort' => ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
 'buttonText' => [
     'month' => 'mes',
     'week' => 'semana',
     'day' => 'día',
     'today' => 'Hoy',
  ],       
  'eventLimit' => true,
];
```